# Vertically Aligning a's in div with unknown height css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

making the navbar of my site a problem occured when I added the logo and my a's floated to the top of the nav  [image]

I tried using flexbox like this
`display:flex; align-items:center;` 
on the topnav class but the a's keep going to the left with the logo

My desired result is to have the a's on the left and vertically centered

```
.logo {
  margin: 7px;
  margin-left:21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height:auto;
}

.topnav {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 70px 0;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <img href="Sindex.php" class="logo" src="Logo.png" alt="logo">
  <a href="#contact">Sign-in/up</a>
  <a href="#news">Order</a>
  <a href="#home" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your `<a>`'s inside a div

and then add to your topnav class:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
```

it should work.